# Scikit-Image: Why won't 'data', 'io', 'viewer' modules import?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I get this error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

when I try to import certain Scikit-image modules, 'data', 'io', 'viewer'. 
The others seem to work fine.
I am using the latest version of Anaconda and Scikit-image (0.13.1). I have v3.6.4 python. System is 32bit windows 10.

[Edit: code used is:

```
from skimage import data
```

and the error produced is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-cde2e39a26a4> in <module>()
----> 1 from skimage import data

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\data\__init__.py in <module>()
     14 
     15 from .. import data_dir
---> 16 from ..io import imread, use_plugin
     17 from .._shared._warnings import expected_warnings
     18 from ._binary_blobs import binary_blobs

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\__init__.py in <module>()
      5 """
      6 
----> 7 from .manage_plugins import *
      8 from .sift import *
      9 from .collection import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\manage_plugins.py in <module>()
     26 from glob import glob
     27 
---> 28 from .collection import imread_collection_wrapper
     29 
     30 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\collection.py in <module>()       
10 import numpy as np
     11 import six
---> 12 from PIL import Image
     13 
     14 from ..external.tifffile import TiffFile

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in <module>()
     56     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
     57     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
---> 58     from . import _imaging as core
     59     if PILLOW_VERSION != getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None):
     60         raise ImportError("The _imaging extension was built for another "

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please show your code that cause the error,

Comment: Hi,  I have edited the question to show the import code and the error. Thanks.

Comment: That's a pillow error. Try to reinstall with `conda install pillow`.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I found a similar answer on Github.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I think I found an answer: looks like a conda issue with Pillow. I reinstalled Pillow from the conda-forge channel:

```
conda install --channel conda-forge pillow=5
```

This solution and further discussion at: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2945